# In selenium how to use xpath to select all imgs that are not in divs with a specific class name

Tags: selenium, xpath

In `selenium`, I want to use `xpath` to select all imgs in the whole `document` that are NOT in divs with a specific class name. I really don't know how to write that, since it seems the `ancestor` or `descendant` wouldn't work. Please help.

Comment: Why ancestor won't work please add the html

Comment: hi @PDHide how would not reverse/negative select based on ancestor?

Comment: xpath has the 'not' operator that you could use even with ancestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[@id="something" and not(@class="aa")]/img
```

did you try not operator of xpath . This will find all div tag with a specific id but not the specified class

So if you want img which doesn't have div as ancestor then :

```
//img[not(ancestor::div)]
```

Comment: This won't work; I want all imgs in the document NOT in those divs. I believe yours will only select imgs that are in some divs but not the ones I want to exclude.

Comment: //Img[not(ancestor::div)]